# How execute file from parent directory without changing directories

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm an enthusiast of efficiency.  I want to execute a file in a parent directory and would appreciate it if anyone knows of a slick way to do it.
I'm using Windows command line.

lets say i have a file: C:\Documents\text.txt
and my current directory is: C:\Documents\pycode

I would like to open the textfile without changing directories or writing entire filepath.

I tried "..\text.txt" but it doesn't work.

Comment: "..\text.txt" is correct if the working directory is really "C:\Documents\pycode" and you're working in CMD or PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Just add quotes.

```
"../text.txt"
```

Or, you can try this:

```
notepad "../text.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help! Just click the checkmark to accept the answer so other people won't try to answer.